# How can I get of the wrapper of Custom action with Aura wrapper of lwc component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, custom-button

I am creating a custom action for publish article in knowledge object. I used an Aura wrapper to wrap the lwc component and then used custom action to point to that (why a wrapper? Because I don't think create a custom action with lwc is currently supported for knowledge object).

So my pop up dialog currently looks like this:
[image]

The thing is, I really don't want to have the cancel button at the bottom. The publish Article head bar is okay but getting rid of it is also okay to me. When I inspect the elements from developer tool it seems like this is coming from Aura or the custom action itself. So how can I remove that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the interface `force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader`, it will show the modal without header and footer. Please find the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader/documentation) for complete details.